# Ошибка срабатывания Геттера в дескрипторе

Tags: javascript

Ранее я уже задавал подобный вопрос, но его закрыли.
Мне завуалированно сказали, что ты дурачек и вопрос мы твой закроем. Как я понял, проблема была в отсутствии свойства куда можно было записать данные из Сеттера. Я добавил это самое свойство, но проблема никуда не ушла, **геттер не хочет работать, то есть выводить сообщение Domik, 28 и значение из Сеттера**

```js
let obj = {};  // Пустой объект
         
Object.defineProperties(obj,{
         
name:{value:'Domik', writable:true,},  // Первое свойство
age:{value: 28, writable:true, },      // Второе свойство
setName:{value: '', writable:true, },  // Третье свойство
         
getterAndSetter:{        // Четвертое свойство

set(setValue){           // Сеттер, полёт  нормальный =)
this.setName = setValue; // Записать результат из prompt в третье свойство
}, 
         
get(){                   // Геттер не хочет работать, почему?
         
alert(`
Текущее имя: ${this.name}, 
Возраст: ${this.age}, 
Ваше имя: ${this.setName}`);   // Должно выводить Domik, 28 и значение из setName
},  
         
enumerable:true,
configurable:true,
},
         
})
         
obj.getterAndSetter =  prompt('Ваше имя?'); // Аргумент Сеттера setValue = prompt
```

Comment: Где в вашем коде использование геттера?

Comment: get(){                   
         
alert(`
Текущее имя: ${this.name}, 
Возраст: ${this.age}, 
Ваше имя: ${this.setName}`);   
},

Comment: Это не 10 тема, а 2. Ответ дали крайне сырой, сказали, что нет свойства, куда можно было записать данные, затем  я добавил это свойство, но результат не изменился. Если вы эксперт, то дайте пожалуйста сюда рабочий пример моего кода. Посмотрим и разберем его.

Comment: @ЯнЗамойский это декларация, а не использование

Comment: И, кстати, неправильное использование. Геттер должен **возвращать** данные, а не вызывать `alert`

Comment: Почему? Но результат тот же. Код работает.

Comment: А сеттер должен записывать данные?  Я хоть сеттер правильно использовал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так работает геттер:

```js
let obj = {};  // Пустой объект
             
Object.defineProperties(obj, {
    name: { value: 'Domik', writable: true },  // Первое свойство
    age: { value: 28, writable: true },      // Второе свойство
    setName: { value: '', writable: true },  // Третье свойство
             
    getterAndSetter: {        // Четвертое свойство
        set(setValue) {           // Сеттер, полёт  нормальный =)
            this.setName = setValue; // Записать результат из prompt в третье свойство
        },
             
        get() {                   // Геттер не хочет работать, почему?
            return `Текущее имя: ${this.name}, 
Возраст: ${this.age}, 
Ваше имя: ${this.setName}`;   // Должно выводить Domik, 28 и значение из setName
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
    },
});
             
obj.getterAndSetter = 'Моё имя'; // Используем сеттер
alert(obj.getterAndSetter); // Используем геттер
```

Comment: Немного стало понятней, но можно напрямую обратиться к любому свойству, что к .name, что к .setName. Тогда зачем весь этот беспредел?

Comment: Оказывается надо было помимо obj.getterAndSetter = prompt  еще раз написать obj.getterAndSetter, чтобы заработал геттер. А в учебнике этого не было сказано, вот я как дурак и возился 2 дня. Как я понимаю в моём случае первый вызов obj.getterAndSetter это сеттер, а второй вызов obj.getterAndSetter это геттер?

Comment: Сеттер вызывается когда вы что-то записываете в свойство (присваиваете ему значение), геттер — когда используете его (читаете его значение).

Comment: *можно напрямую обратиться к любому свойству* — да, но только потому что вы так написали. Часто сеттер может использоваться для проверки перед присваиванием. https://learn.javascript.ru/private-protected-properties-methods

Comment: @ЯнЗамойский, то есть в этих условиях вы хотите так: `obj.getterAndSetter = obj.getterAndSetter; console.log(obj.setName);` ? Это все зачем? Чтобы кого запутать?

Comment: @Alexey Ten, я хоть сеттер правильно использовал?